# delete first/last occurrence in list python

Tags: python

I need to delete all first occurrence in list.

time limit = 2 s.

memory limit = 256 mb.

Given list a. Some elements in a repeated. If len(a) = 1 print 0.

Input: 1 1 5 2 4 3 3 4 2 5.

Output: 1 3 4 2 5

My solution: For 48 test 22 - good. Else - limited time. How it solve without .count

```
n = int(input())
A = list(map(int, input().split()))
C = []

if len(A) == 1:
    print(0)
else:
    for j in range(n):
        if A[:j].count(A[j]):
            C.append(A[j])
    print(len(C))
    print(*C)
```

Pls help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is good that you attempted to solve the problem before posting it here. However, people here are encouraged to as a specific question (After doing X, why do I get Y instead of Z?) rather than ask for a solution (how do I get Z?).

Answer (score 1):

Another way than using sets

**First**

```
n = input().split(" ")
u = []
if(len(n) == 1): print(0, end="")
else: 
  d = {}
  for a in n: 
    if a in d: u.append(int(a))
    else: d[a] = 1 
print(*u, end="")

# input: 1 1 5 2 4 3 3 4 2 5
# output: 1 3 4 2 5
# input: 5
# output: 0
# input: 1 1 1 1
# output: 1 1 1
```

**Last**

```
n = input().split(" ")
u = []
if(len(n) == 1): print(0, end="")
else:
  n.reverse()
  d = {}
  for a in n: 
    if a in d: u.append(int(a))
    else: d[a] = 1 
  u.reverse()
print(*u, end="")
# # input: 1 1 5 2 4 3 3 4 2 5
# # output: 1 5 2 4 3
# # input: 5
# # output: 0
# # input: 1 1 1 1
# # output: 1 1 1
```

Comment: if a = [ 1, 1, 1, 1], with set => wrong answer: 1. correct answer: 1 1 1

Comment: Well I guess I didn't see your first line  "I need to delete all first occurrence in list.", so I thought you need to get rid of duplicates, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates use set()

```
_ = input()
A = set(map(int, input().split()))
print(*list(A))
```

Comment: if a = [ 1, 1, 1, 1], with set => wrong answer: 1. correct answer: 1 1 1